# How to check a value of a variable and call different function

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have the following variables in my cart.php file:

```
<?php $readyTotal = $qty*price ?>;
```

Now I want to do is that if the $readyTotal > $1000 then call a file which is adding an item into the customer's cart.

```
($slq= msyql_query("INSERT into `table`.....value.....");
```

and if the value of $radyTotal < $1000;

dont add any extra item or if it has been added just remove it by calling the removal file.

```
($sql =mysql_query("DELETE from `table` where .......");
```

Please note that how to do this I want to call/include the files in my cart.php file. but i am unable to do this. is there any other way to do it or by using ajax/jquery which check every the value of $readyTotal every time when it changes.

```
function ad(){
    $signature =getSignature(); 
        $item = 21;
        $type = 100;
        $type= 0;
        $sql2 = mysql_query("Select * From `temp` where `item`='$item' AND `price`= 0 AND
        `signature`='$signature' AND `type`=0 AND `toppings`=0 " );

        $count= mysql_num_rows($sql2);

        if($count ==0){
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `temp`  
        (`item`,`price`,`signature`,`type`,`toppings`, `isCoupon`) 
        VALUES 
        ('$item','$type','$signature','0','0', '1')");

        }
}
function removeMe(){
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM `temp` WHERE `item`=21 AND `signature`='".getSignature()."'");
}
```

When I try the above function individual file it works fine, but when i use both in it does not woks please.... what is wrong with this...

Comment: Why you have to include file, even you can achieve it by just calling your custom function?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
  include_once("customfunctionfile.php");
  $object = new quiz;
  $readyTotal = $qty*price ;

  if($readyTotal > 1000){
    $object->ad();
  }else{
     $object->removeMe();
  }
```

?>;

customfunctionfile.php

```
class quiz{
  function ad(){
  $signature =getSignature(); 
    $item = 21;
    $type = 100;
    $type= 0;
    $sql2 = mysql_query("Select * From `temp` where `item`='$item' AND   `price`= 0 AND
    `signature`='$signature' AND `type`=0 AND `toppings`=0 " );

    $count= mysql_num_rows($sql2);

    if($count ==0){
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `temp`  
    (`item`,`price`,`signature`,`type`,`toppings`, `isCoupon`) 
    VALUES 
    ('$item','$type','$signature','0','0', '1')");

    }

   }
    function removeMe(){
       mysql_query("DELETE FROM `temp` WHERE `item`=21 AND   
       `signature`='".getSignature()."'");
     }
}
```

Comment: Sir, I have edit my question, please have a glance now.

Comment: I have updated the code , this will work and read about classes

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this something like this using functions without including file.

```
<?php
$readyTotal = $qty*price;

if($readyTotal > 1000) //considering amount in $
{
  addItemToCart($cartDetails) // call function to add item into the cart
}
else {
  removeItemFromCart($cartDetails)  //call function to remove item from cart
}
?>
```

Define functions `addItemToCart` and `removeItemFromCart` to fire your queries.

Comment: Sir, I have edit my question, please have a glance now. It dos not work ... I was trying the same way

Comment: I think you need to debug you code to check if `ad()` and `removeMe()` functions are calling properly.

Comment: How to do with ajax. please help anyone please